# Webpack 4 - JSON module not found

Tags: json, typescript, webpack

I have some JSON files in my Webpack application that I want to import. They have names such as `0.json`, `1.json`, `2.json`, and so on and are inside of the directory `src/res/level/`. When I try to `require()` them in my code, it does not work:

```
private loadWorld() {

    // load the level
    // duplicate the object to avoid modifying the actual instance
    // that json-loader created
    this.state.level = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require(`@res/level/${this.level}.json`))) as LevelData;

    // ...

}
```

This line in my method always throws an error:

> ```
> Error: Cannot find module "@res/level/1.json".
>     at webpackContextResolve (webpack-internal:///9:16:11)
>     at webpackContext (webpack-internal:///9:9:11)
> ```

However, I cannot figure out why. And to make things more confusing, if I run Webpack in watch mode, and I edit this line *before* my program tries to run it, then the JSON files are suddenly loaded properly.

I have configured my alias for `@res` properly:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".glsl", ".json"],
    alias: {
        "@res": path.join(__dirname, "src/res"),
        "@lib": path.join(__dirname, "src/lib"),
        "@shader": path.join(__dirname, "src/shader"),
        "@control": path.join(__dirname, "src/control"),
        "@scene": path.join(__dirname, "src/scene"),
        "@util": path.join(__dirname, "src/util"),
    }
}
```

And because this is Webpack 4, I simply did not include a loader for JSON.
So why is this not working?

Additionally, I notice that when I inspect the generated code, I see this:
[image]

Which suggests that the JSON files are being loaded, but not under the directory that I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler began to load the JSON files consistently when I used string concatenation instead of a template string:

```
this.state.level = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require("@res/level/" + this.level.toString() + ".json"))) as LevelData;
```